# find a string in a column but return the value in a different column under the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
Car | Color | Year | Price
VW  | blue  | 2014 | 20,000
Audi| red   | 2017 | 30,000
```

I am using IF for this as this table is not exactly my real df, just need an idea.

I need the price of the vehicle if the selection is Audi lets say.

I am looking for s substring in a string but I just need the cost of one specific column in the exact row where the substring was found.

I am using:

```
for x in cars['Car']:
   if "Audi" in x:
      #Just need the row in column 'Price'
      print(??)
```

Comment: can you give a clear example of what you want? ideally follow the instructions to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like you only need a boolean mask, df.filter, or df.query, but as others have said it's tough to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with `iterrows` to check if any row's `Car` contains `Audi`.

```
for index, row in cars.iterrows():
    if 'Audi' in row.Car:
        print(row.Price)
```

Comment: Thanks sr, I was stupidly doing it as a series instead of the df. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing with pandas.

```
df[df['Car'].str.contains('Audi')]['Price']
```

To break it down:

```
    df['Car']                                   # Select Car column
    df['Car'].str.contains('Audi')              # Check if the value for each row contains Audi
    df[df['Car'].str.contains('Audi')]          # Select rows where contains Audi is true
    df[df['Car'].str.contains('Audi')]['Price'] # Select the price column only
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't go for string comparision you can directly use `pd.groupby()` function like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
listt = [['VW','blue',2014,20000],
         ['Audi','red',2015,30000],
         ['BMW','black',2019,90000],
         ['Audi','white',2011,70000]]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(listt)
my_df.columns=(['Car','Color','Year','Price'])

grouped_data = my_df.groupby('Car')
grouped_data.get_group("Audi")
```

OutPut :

```
    Car  Color  Year  Price
1  Audi    red  2015  30000
3  Audi  white  2011  70000
```